# RegEx replacement in string

Tags: regex, apache-flex, flex3

I have a string and I am using RegEx to match and replace a pattern.

'*x00..*' where .. are two wild characters. I want to replace this with %..' and retain the two characters.

I cannot do this in two step-
'*x00' and replace with '%'
and second step '*' replace with ''

As I have other occurrences _ in the string which I do not want to replace.

This is in flex 3.

I want to achieve something like this-

```
var pat:RegExp = new RegExp('%.._','/g');
str = str.replace(pat,'%..');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What language/software/lib do you use ?

Comment: Then add the tag. It's more about flex 3 than about regexp.